# Initialize object pointer in another class with function pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the following.  Class `A` has a function pointer as a member and accepts a function in its constructor to pass to this member.  In a separate file, I have a class `B` that contains a pointer to class `A` as a member, and class `B` also has as a member the function I want to pass to class `A`.

Below is an example and the errors I receive.  What's the standard method of doing something like this?

A.h:

```
class A {
 private:
  int (*func)(int);

 public:
  A(int (*func_)(int));
};

A::A(int (*func_)(int)) : func(func_) {}
```

B.h:

```
#include "A.h"  // Why can't I forward declare A instead?

class B {
 private:
  A *A_ptr;
  int function(int);  // some function

 public:
  B();
  ~B();
};

int B::function(int n) {
  return n+2;  // some return value
}

B::B() {
  A_ptr = new A(function);
}

B::~B() {
  delete A_ptr;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"

int main() {
  B b;
}
```

Errors I get:

```
B.h: In constructor ‘B::B()’:
B.h:18:25: error: no matching function for call to ‘A::A(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
B.h:18:25: note: candidates are:
A.h:9:1: note: A::A(int (*)(int))
A.h:9:1: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘int (*)(int)’
A.h:1:7: note: A::A(const A&)
A.h:1:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘const A&’
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question regarding "What's the standard method of doing something like this" I'll assume you mean passing member functions and/or general function pointers around and executing them with some data. Some popular implementations which provide this ability are:

1. [FastDelegate](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible)
2. [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)
3. [boost::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/doc/html/function/tutorial.html)

It really comes down to preference and library choice. Personally, I've used FastDelegate most of the time and then std::function after that.

All the links I posted should have tutorial information to get you up and running and show you how to properly pass and store member functions and/or general function pointers with ease.

Here's an example of using a FastDelegate with your example:

```
class A 
{
public:
    // [1] This creates a delegate type. Can used for any function, 
    // class function, static function, that takes one int 
    // and has a return type of an int.
    typedef FastDelegate1< int, int > Delegate;

    // [2] Pass the delegate into 'A' and save a copy of it.
    A( const Delegate& delegate ) : _delegate( delegate ) { };

    void execute()
    {
        // [7]
        // Result should be 10!
        int result = _delegate( 8 ); 
    }

private:
    // [3] Storage to save the Delegate in A.
    Delegate _delegate;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() 
    {
        // [4] Create the delegate
        A::Delegate bDelegate;
        bDelegate.bind( this, &B::function );

        // [5] Create 'A' passing in the delegate.            
        _aPtr = new A( bDelegate );

        // [6] Test it out!! :) 
        // This causes `A` to execute the Delegate which calls B::function. 
        _aPtr->execute();
    }

    ~B() 
    {
        delete _aPtr; 
    }

    int function( int n )
    {
        return n+2;
    }

private:
    A* _aPtr;
};
```

Comment: Cool, thanks for the links!  My example actually works if I declare `function` as `static` in class `B`, but I'm not sure why.  Would you happen to know?

Comment: It work because in simple terms adding `static` causes `function` to no longer have a `this` aka `B` pointer. It still maintains its class scope with `B` but no longer requires an object `B` for the function to be executed upon. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yyh8hetw.aspx it was one of the simpler explanations I could find. Again this is a pretty low level explanation of static's impact in this case.

Comment: @bcf Added an example of the `FastDelegate` method. The learning curve of using any type of implementation I listed is more than simply using a pointer type but it's worth it in my opinion as you'll be able to build more generic and dynamic solutions. Whichever solution you pick I would say a good practice task would be to implement a 'command' pattern using them :) Good luck!